# How to type “田” with filled upper left and lower right sub-squares?

Tags: symbols

How to type “田” with filled upper left sub-square and lower right sub-square as a character in LaTeX?

Comment: You should check out the latex symbols documentation from page 118 onwards. There are a lot of symbols similar (the one you provided is called \boxplus) but I didn't see one filled how you said. ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf

Comment: Try using the `picture` environment, with the `\put` and `\rule` commands, perhaps.

Comment: Note that 田 is a CJK character, not a picture (it means "rice paddy" in Japanese).  In many fonts it is more trapezoidal than square.  It is not recommended to use CJK characters for drawing pictures, unless you're on a BBS.

Answer (score 11):

Without using any graphic packages (like [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks)), you can typeset a checkered box `\cbox` using `\rule` and `\fbox`. Rules take the following arguments:

```
\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<height>}
```

while `\fbox` has a rule width of `\fboxrule` and separation of `\fboxsep`. As such, the following minimal example provides `\cbox` with a NW/SE checkered box and `\cbox*` with a NE/SW checkered box. The current box width/height has a default of `1ex`, although this can be modified by means of an optional `<width>` argument `\cbox[*][<width>]`. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides the starred interface, although it could be done without.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\cbox}{s O{1ex}}{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Condition on starred/unstarred
    {\frame{\rule{0.5\dimexpr#2}{0.5\dimexpr#2}\rule[0.5\dimexpr#2]{0.5\dimexpr#2}{0.5\dimexpr#2}}}% \mybox*
    {\fbox{\rule[0.5\dimexpr#2]{0.5\dimexpr#2}{0.5\dimexpr#2}\rule{0.5\dimexpr#2}{0.5\dimexpr#2}}}% \mybox
  \xspace% Possible space
}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \verb!\cbox!: & \cbox \\
  \verb!\cbox*!: & \cbox* \\
  \verb!\cbox[20pt]!: & \cbox[20pt] \\
  \verb!\cbox*[1.5em]!: & \cbox*[1.5em]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Using `\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}` removes any separation between the box contents the the surrounding/boxed rule. [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) corrects for any missed spacing correction after the control sequence.

Comment: You may use `\frame` instead of `\fbox` to avoid extra width and height by `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.

Comment: Thanks, but with `\frame` only the lower rule is below the baseline.

Answer (score 8):

You might like my package `ytableau`, which does this easily by design:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
 \begin{ytableau}
  *(black) & \\
   & *(black)
 \end{ytableau}
 \medskip

 \ytableaushort{ {*(black)} {} , {} {*(black)} }
 \medskip

 \ydiagram[*(black)]{1,1+1} * {2,2}
 \medskip

 \ytableausetup{boxsize = 6pt}
 \ydiagram[*(black)]{1,1+1} * {2,2}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output: three big boxes and one small one]

It's supposed to produce [Young tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) in mathematics, but there's no reason not to use it for general box-piling.  The syntax for this is very simple.

- You can use the environment form, which is just like any array-like environment, but also takes color specifications set off by a `*` and with the color in parentheses (anything accepted by `xcolor` is good).
- There's also a short form, where the rows are lists of cells (possibly enclosed in braces if they are not just single characters) with the same color specification syntax.
- There's also the Young diagram form, which doesn't allow anything in the boxes, but takes an optional argument that is put in *every* box, which can of course be a color specification.  You can give it offsets in each row: `1+1` means "skip one space, then put one box".  That's what you wanted for the black box in the second row.
- There's also the "chaining" operation: either the short form or the Young diagram can be followed by a `*` and then *another* argument list, which can only be for a Young diagram, possibly with an optional argument.  The first diagram (either tableau or diagram) is then piled on top of the successive diagrams with the leftmost ones being on the upper layers.  This way, you can construct complex color patterns.
- It also has a `\ytableausetup` command that changes a few things, in this case, the box size.  You'll have to read [the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ytableau/ytableau.pdf) for the full story there.

The package is [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau), and therefore, also in TeX Live and (I think) MikTeX.

Comment: Thanks! Guys,
Could you tell me how to install "ytableau" package?
I checked the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau.
There is no specific "Download" button.

Comment: @Dan I converted your answer into a comment since it's not a real answer. Your question won't be seen by many people here so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background. However, please have a look at the [existing questions about installing packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing+packages).

Comment: @Dan: First of all, did you check your package manager?  Anything that's been on CTAN for a while should be in there.  If you must install by hand: packages on CTAN are usually distributed as a `.dtx` and a `.ins` file, from which you can get the actual package and the documentation.  To get the package, run latex on `ytableau.ins`; to get the manual, run pdflatex on `ytableau.dtx`.  Put them in `<personal texmf tree>/tex/latex/ytableau`.

Comment: @Dan: Also, see http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=installthings; this is a very Frequently Asked Question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that symbol listed anywhere but since you are in a hurry you could consider drawing it with tikz:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Start with text, create the picture
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(0,.5)--(.5,.5)--(.5,0)--cycle;
\filldraw (0,.5)--(.25,.5)--(.25,.25)--(0,.25);
\filldraw (.25,.25)--(.5,.25)--(.5,0)--(.25,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
and then some more text.
\end{document}
```

By varying the coordinates, you can make the symbol as big or small as you want.

Comment: You could use `ex` or `em` units for specifying the size, which will make the symbol scale with the surrounding text. Also, you could simplify your code by using `\draw <corner> rectangle <opposite corner>;`. I would suggest rewriting your code as something like `\draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (1.5ex,1.5ex);
\fill (0,1.5ex) rectangle (0.75ex,0.75ex);
\fill (0.75ex,0.75ex) rectangle (1.5ex,0pt);`

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I still haven't gotten far in the tikz manual.